# Newbie Q - what's happening when I leave out a variable in printf

Tags: c

I'm learning C for fun. In one of my first bits of code (via 'Learn C the Hard Way') I've deliberately left out the variable in a printf statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int age = 3;

  printf("I am %d years old.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Pretty simple. It compiles and throws earnings as I expect. But when I foolishly run the broken program anyway, I get an unusual output:

```
I am 1476430496 years old.
```

Each time I run it, the number is different but similar. I thought maybe it's a memory address for 'age' so I tried:

```
printf("age is %p\n", &age);
```

But that's not it:

```
I am 1570798240 years old.
age is 0x7fff5da07a78
```

So I'm curious. What is this number? Where does it come from? I tried different output types (%s, %e, %u) and things got weirder.

As a follow up question, when I tried %p with no variable, I *did* get a memory address.

```
I am 0x7fff53e8caa0 years old.
```

I'm also curious to where this address came from? Is there any way I can see what might be in it?

Thanks for your time and any help you can offer!

Mike

Comment: This is called [_undefined behavior_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In other words, those values have no specified meaning according to the C standard; they're probably just whatever the compiled code happens to grab out of memory.

Comment: This is an UB. In your case `printf` parses format string and takes specified amount of arguments from the stack. Since you have not provided these arguments - you get some memory garbage instead. Different compiler/system may yeld different results.

Comment: C is powerful. It will give you freedom to do wonderful things, like shoot yourself in the foot. Pay attention to the warnings. They're usually not petty complaints.

Comment: This is what is often called "garbage data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Printf` will try to read as many variables as you specify in the format string. In this case, it's reading the next 4 or 8 bytes off the stack and interpreting it as an integer or pointer, because you told it there would be an integer or pointer there.

Whatever happened to be there is what you are seeing. It's entirely possible that it's some bytes left by a process that previously executed in that memory space.

As others point out the behavior is technically undefined by the language, you could write your compiler to implement this case in any number of ways, including crashing. It just happens that the most straightforward thing to do is to trust the format string and keep reading, and usually there's enough space mapped for the stack for this to return *something*.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined behavior**.

> printf() does not change the contents of the variables you pass to it,
>   so you simply pass the values of the variables.

You can read about **format specifiers for printf** from the manual. Format specifier mismatch in printf leads to [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).